# Is there a way to automatically transfer photos from a DSLR to a PC hard disk as they are taken?

Tags: canon, nikon, usb, tablet, file-transfer

I have a need to have photos taken either on a modern Nikon or on a modern Canon DSLR automatically be transfered via USB cable to a Windows hard disk.

It would work like this - at an event, a photographer would roam around and take photos of people. The camera, meanwhile, is connected constantly to a tablet running Win7 via USB. Each time the photographer takes a photo, the photo would be transmitted to the tablet directly to a folder on the hard disk. Our software would then take over from there.

Could someone recommend software that would accomplish this? (for modern/recent cameras of course).

I came across the following, and am not sure if they would do what I want. Any guidance would be much appreciated, thanks!!

Nikon's software: Camera Control Pro 2: http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Imaging-Software/25366/Camera-Control-Pro-2.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-Overview

A 3rd party solution for Canon's:

Comment: I think Canon's come with software that you can use to do Tethered shooting... Have you also considered something like: http://uk.eye.fi/

Comment: Lightroom also supports tethered shooting with both Nikon and Canon bodies that support tethering. Conveniently, Lightroom is running a mere [$69 at B&H](http://www.canonrumors.com/2012/02/adobe-lightroom-3-for-69-at-bh/) right now.

Comment: Tethered shooting is enabled using Canon's EOS Utility that comes with the camera.

Comment: 3rd party canon link is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of software programs that will handle tethered shooting: Lightroom 4, Phase One software's [Capture One](http://www.phaseone.com/en/Software/Capture-One-Pro-6/About/Pro-Overview.aspx) (which will also wireless transmit images to an iPad using [Capture Pilot](http://www.phaseone.com/en/Software/Capture-Pilot/Overview.aspx).  These are full blown editing suites however.

If you just want simple transfer, what about an [Eye-Fi](http://www.eye.fi/how-it-works/basics) card?  They have a direct mode which will send images wirelessly to Android, iOS.  Not sure about a Win7 tablet.

Answer (score 15):

It sounds like what you want is an [Eye-Fi card](http://uk.eye.fi/).  This will wirelessly transmit the photos you take as you walk round back to your PC.  If you go for this option though you will need to use one of Canon's xxxxD or xxxD series cameras as it's SD Card only at the moment - no Compact Flash card option... (Thus, 7D / 5D series / 50D and before / 1D series can't use it yet, though the 60D now has an SD card slot).

However if as you say, the camera is to be connected via. USB (I can't see how this would work if your photographer is walking around the room though), then Canon's own bundled [EOS Utility](http://www.canon.co.uk/for_home/product_finder/cameras/digital_slr/eos30d/software/eosutility.asp) supports tethered shooting and transferring of pictures to the PC...

Comment: a lot of tablet computers have accessories that allow them to be worn "hands free", usually with a shoulder sling.

Comment: It appears EyeFi now produces a CF to SD converter to pair with their SD cards.

Comment: My 70D explicitly supports the EyeFI in the menu options.

Comment: eye-fi link is dead, anyone have an updated one?

Answer (score 3):

The magic word is "tethered." Others have named some software that will do it, but anything that lets you shoot tethered will do it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/consumer_cameras_wft/wireless_transmitter_wft_e5a) is pretty cool if you happen to have a 7D.

Comment: Damn! +1 for this...  I have a 7D and completely forgot about this option!! -- I have the standard BG-E7 grip for it... :)

Comment: Yes cool, but unbelievable how much they ask for that thing ($600USD).

Comment: There are different options for multiple canon cameras on that site.  The 7D is only one of this list http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/consumer_cameras_wft

Answer (score 1):

I think eyefi will transfer photos whenever there's a connection available, whereas shooting tethered (Wifi/wired/6dwifi) will only transfer photos while there is a connection avail.

If you want to shoot tethered (cable/wifi) the EOS utility has an option to open an application with the image given to it, via command line I presume. This could be an option. Alternatively, the EOS utility can copy the jpeg to a folder and have your application monitor the folder and do something when the photo comes in.

---

Edit1:
NB: This is how I think eyefi works, I don't have one. But this is my understanding.
Eyefi will automagically transfer photos from the memory card to the computer whenever a wifi connection becomes available.

Tethered will only automagically transfer photos taken while the connection is available. If you take photos when not tethered, and suddenly tether, then they won't be magically copied over. You need to do some clicking on the computer to make them copy. But, the pictures taken while you tether will be copied.

So, if in your room your wifi tether drops out then those photos won't be copied over. Whereas with eyefi they will be copied when the connection is reestablished.

Comment: Can you clarify your first sentence? What's the difference?

Answer (score -1):

Breeze Systems has some products (DSLR Remote Pro, NKRemote) that might be what you are looking for:
http://www.breezesys.com/products.htm

Answer (score -1):

> Could someone recommend software that would accomplish this? (for modern/recent cameras of course).

EOS Utility, a part of the software included with all Canon DSLRs, allows you to shoot tethered and transfers the image file to the folder you have designated on your computer.

There is a 13 part tutorial series at [Canon's Digital Learning Center](http://www.learn.usa.canon.com/galleries/galleries/tutorials/eos_util_isola_gallery.shtml).