# What setup or software do I need to see/ have live access to images as I take them from a DSLR?

Tags: tethering, panasonic-lumix

Is there a setup that I can have that allows me to have access to the images being taken from a DSLR. That way I can select the one I want and change the name on the spot etc... [image] The camera that I'm currently using is a Panasonic Lumix GH5.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20299/9161

Comment: Where, exactly, do you wish to see the images? On one of the camera's screens? On a smartphone or other mobile device? On a PC/Mac? Transmitted directly to your optic nerve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I have the LiveView of my camera displayed on a TV or Laptop screen?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42785/how-can-i-have-the-liveview-of-my-camera-displayed-on-a-tv-or-laptop-screen)

Comment: Also related: [Is there a way to automatically transfer photos from a DSLR to a PC hard disk as they are taken?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/20299/15871)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panasonic have a Mac/Win tethering solution - https://av.jpn.support.panasonic.com/support/global/cs/soft/download/d_lumixtether.html

idk whether it would satisfy your need, but as the images would be straight to your Mac, presumably you could sort by date so your last image is at the top then use Finder to rename.

Comment: Thank you will check this out.